# how to upload project folder on github branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, github, github-pages

Well I'm working on rails project. Well I want o upload updated version of whole application on github branch name "dev_Bee". So can you tell me the step wise procedure how to upload my application on a specific branch. Well I'm working on ubuntu so please try to give commands for ubuntu.

Comment: This depends on the git client you use. In general, the steps would be to create a new branch, commit your changes to it and push it. The mental model for that is explained in about any git introduction ("working with branches"). Similarly, your chosen client will likely describe how to work with branches in their help too.

Comment: git checkout -b dev_Bee, git push origin dev_Bee. This is Holger's answer but version TL;DR. You could have easily found this information by doing a quick google search or looking into any basic git tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using rails I'll assume your project has already git initiated.

First, you need to stage all the changes and commit

`git add .
git commit -m 'Your Commit Message Here'`

Then checkout to a new branch of your desired name
`git checkout -b dev_Bee`

Set your remote repository

`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<gitusernamehere>/<git-repo-name-here>.git`

And finally push the changes to remote
`git push -u origin dev_Bee`